# sending a mesage with a header and body out a serial port with java

Tags: java, serial-port

I've searched high and low and havn't been able to find an answer to this question.  I'm fairly certain that it isn't difficult, probably a case of my searches not using the right verbiage.

I'm working on communicating with a gimbal controller. I've been able to connect to the serial port that it's connected to.  I'm unable to find information on how to format a message like this:

> Each command consists
>   of the header and the body, both with checksum. Commands with the wrong header or body checksum, or
>   with the body size that differs from expected, should be ignored.

Can anyone point me in the direction on how to write to the serial port like that?

Thank you,

Loren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two typical approaches for communicating with a device over a serial port. In both cases, the end result is raw bits being sent over the wire. You can send ASCII strings if your device expects it but since your excerpt specifically mentioned packet packaging, I would venture to say that they want bytes.

The excerpt you copy pasted sounds like it came from a manual that explains the exact protocol that is required to communicate. In a nutshell, you will be doing the following.

1. Setup the serial port
2. Prepare your serial data
3. Send your serial data

I like to use jSSC for serial comms though lots of other folks use RXTX. jSSC has been more reliable for me so that's what I'll be using in my example. The manual for your device should specify the required baud rate, data bits, stop bits, parity, and handshake (if any).

Here we setup a port (replace your parameters as needed). See the docs on the details of this. https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector

```
SerialPort _port = new SerialPort(portName);
_port .openPort();
_port.setParams(baudRate, dataBits, stopBits, parity, setRTS, setDTR);  
_port.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
```

To construct your data packet, you will need to know:

1. Header format
2. Length requirement/restrictions
3. Checksum method

Here I am going to make a super simple packet that is just an example and is most likely not applicable to your use case.

```
// Format is: [length][7 data bytes][8 bit additive checksum]
// Create an empty byte array
byte[] packet = new byte[8];

// Our simple header
packet[0] = packet.length;

// Some data
byte[] dummyData = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

// Copy data to packet
System.arraycopy(dummyData, 0, packet, 0, dummyData.length);

// Go do the checksum (good exercise for you)
byte checksum = getChecksum(packet);
packet[7] = checksum;
```

So now we have a port, some data... and now what? Let's send it.

```
// Just send those bytes
_port.writeBytes(packet);
```

Once you get the hang of things, read into how you read the response, setup OnDataReceivedEvents, and how to more efficiently create packets. Some good terms to Google:

- jSSC
- Java RXTX
- Baud Rate
- Async/Sync data handling

Comment: Wow this is great!  Thank you very much